# Plot time windows based on interested value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I use the following code to identify some interested values into a dataframe and them plot a time window before and after that value appeared. It works very well, but I would like to know if there is a less coding way/more pythonic way to accomplish this. Thanks in advance!

Before I go, I try to use only Seaborn on the plotting secction, but creating the subplots and filling then was easier, considering I don't want to share axis.

```
# Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Generate Data
rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range(start="1/1/2019", periods=1035, freq='D'),
    data={'value':rng.integers(-100, 30000, 1035)}
).reset_index()

# Creating a boolean for interesting values
df['select'] = df['value'] < 0

# Finding days with interested value and creating the periods
lt_dates = df.loc[df['select'], 'index'].to_list()
lt_days_after = [pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=day, periods=14, freq='D')).reset_index() for day in lt_dates]
lt_days_before = [pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(end=day, periods=14, freq='D')).reset_index() for day in lt_dates]

# Concatenating the periods
df_mask = pd.concat(objs=[pd.concat(lt_days_after), pd.concat(lt_days_before)]).sort_values('index').drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)

# Flagging days
df['grouped'] = df['index'].isin(df_mask['index'])

# Creating the groups
df['slice'] = (~df['grouped']).cumsum()
groups = df.loc[df['grouped'], 'slice'].unique()
groups_dict = {y: x for x, y in enumerate(groups)}

# Filtering non interested values
df = df.loc[df['grouped']]

df['slice'].replace(groups_dict, inplace=True)

# Plotting
rows = len(groups_dict)

# Function to fill the subplots
def subplot_df(_ax, x):
        sns.lineplot(
            x="index",
            y='value',
            ci=None,
            data=df[df['slice'] == x],
            ax=_ax
        )
        _ax.set_xlabel('')

f, ax = plt.subplots(
    nrows=rows,
    figsize=(12, 2*rows),
    sharex=False,
    sharey=False
)

# Filling a single or multiple subplots
if rows != 0:
    for x in range(rows):
        subplot_df(ax[x], x)
else:
    subplot_df(ax, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid passing strings for parameters like `start` when they come from application constants and not the user; use `date` instances instead.

You rely on `reset_index` too much - this can go away and be replaced with direct construction of the dataframe. One consequence of your approach is that there's a column called `index`, which is not a good idea because attribute access for the column is broken (i.e. you can't write `df.index`).

Your use of `isin`, the separate treatment of `after` and `before`, and your `enumerate` and `replace` can go away. Consider instead a broadcast comparison of time deltas.

### Suggested

```
from datetime import date

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'when': pd.date_range(
        start=date(2019, 1, 1), periods=1035, freq='D'
    ),
    'value': rng.integers(low=-100, high=30_000, size=1035)
})

# Creating a boolean for interesting values
selected = df.value < 0

all_selected = np.abs(
    df['when'].values[:, np.newaxis] -
    df['when'][selected].values[np.newaxis, :]
) < pd.to_timedelta(14, unit='D')

df['grouped'] = np.bitwise_or.reduce(all_selected, axis=1)
grouped = np.zeros(1+len(selected), dtype=bool)
grouped[1:] = df.grouped
changes = np.abs(np.diff(grouped))
df['slice'] = changes.cumsum() // 2

# Filtering non interesting values
df = df.loc[df.grouped, :]

# Plotting
rows = round(changes.sum() // 2)

# Function to fill the subplots
def subplot_df(ax: plt.Axes, x: int) -> None:
    sns.lineplot(
        x='when',
        y='value',
        ci=None,
        data=df[df['slice'] == x],
        ax=ax,
    )
    ax.set_xlabel('')


f, ax = plt.subplots(
    nrows=rows,
    figsize=(12, 2*rows),
    sharex=False,
    sharey=False,
)

# Filling a single or multiple subplots
if rows == 0:
    subplot_df(ax, 0)
else:
    for x in range(rows):
        subplot_df(ax[x], x)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain to me two points? 1. I tried to read the **np.bitwise_or.reduce** documentation, but I am straggling to get what this function does. I don’t know if my language or my computation skills are limited. 2. And, on following the first question, I don’t understand mathematically speaking why make necessary the // division. Thanks for your support!

Comment: See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html

Comment: Given a 4*n array of boolean, that applies 'or' over the smaller axis to produce an array of length `n`

Comment: Floor division is necessary in that case because you don't want group indices of 0.5 and so on: those need to be integers